# return indices of duplicated elements corresponding to the unique elements in R

Tags: r, matlab, duplicates, unique, uniqueidentifier

anyone know if there's a build in function in R that can return indices of duplicated elements corresponding to the unique elements?
For instance I have a vector 
    a <- ["A","B","B","C","C"]
unique(a) will give ["A","B","C"]
duplicated(a) will give [F,F,T,F,T]
is there a build-in function to get a vector of indices for the same length as original vector a, that shows the location a's elements in the unique vecor (which is [1,2,2,3,3] in this example)?

i.e., something like the output variable "ic" in the matlab function "unique". (which is, if we let c = unique(a), then a = c(ic,:)).
http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html

Thank you!

Comment: I guess you know this, but `a <- ["A","B","B","C","C"]` is not R code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use `match`

```
match(a, unique(a))
#[1] 1 2 2 3 3
```

Or convert to `factor` and coerce to `integer`

```
as.integer(factor(a, levels = unique(a)))
#[1] 1 2 2 3 3
```

#### data

```
a <- c("A","B","B","C","C")
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
cumsum( !duplicated( sort( a)) )  # one you replace  Mathlab syntax with R syntax.
```

Or just:

```
as.numeric(factor(a) )
```